# What does the -> <- operator do?

Tags: java, syntax, lambda, obfuscation, java-8

I recently came upon the following code:

```
IntPredicate neg = x -> x <- x;
```

What is this, some sort of reverse double lambda?

Comment: My guess: Lambda `(x) -> (x < -x)`

Comment: I am tempted to vote to close for "simple typographical error." ;)

Comment: That's an example what parentheses are sometimes good for.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the [--> operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator)

Comment: @rightfold I disagree. The "duplicate" question is about C++, not Java, and this question was asked years before Java introduced lambda expressions.

Comment: BTW, `x < -x` is broken for testing if `x` is negative. It will fail in the case where `x == Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @spryno724 Uh, I know. Yet it’s pretty much exactly the same problem: obfuscated operators.

Comment: Reverse double lambda, man does that sound scary

Comment: @rightfold They're both about obfuscated operators, but that doesn't mean that reading the answer to the other question would give you the answer to this one. I find it hard to consider it a duplicate for that reason.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Reading the answer to the other question will immediately ring a bell and the reader would conclude that the latter `-` here is in fact the unary negation operator.

Comment: @rightfold That's hardly guaranteed. You or I might, but someone else who's going through a hard day might still have trouble parsing what's going on. In any case, since it's not an *exact* duplicate it becomes somewhat subjective, and the lack of close votes seems to indicate that most people want the question to stay.

Comment: Really? You really came across this code in an actual program written for some practical purpose?

Comment: @righfold duplicate answer != duplicate question...

Comment: Oh man... I hate developers who write damn difficult to understand code like `x -> x <- x` or [-->](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator) or something like that that looks _cool ASCII art_.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

There is no `-> <-` operator. That first `->` is just lambda syntax, as introduced in Java 8, and that second `<-` is a misleading concatenation of 'smaller than' `<` and 'unary minus' `-`.

You can read it as `IntPredicate neg = (x) -> (x < (-x));`, i.e. it tests whether `x` is smaller than `-x`, which is the case for all (well, [most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938333/what-does-the-operator-do/24938462#comment38754811_24938462)) negative numbers, hence the name `neg`.

```
IntPredicate neg = x -> x <- x;
System.out.println(neg.test(4));   // false
System.out.println(neg.test(0));   // false
System.out.println(neg.test(-4));  // true
```

---

Just for completeness: This test is not only (intentionally?) hard to understand, but -- as pointed out in the comments -- it also fails for `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (which is `==-Integer.MIN_VALUE`). Instead, you should probably just use the much simpler `IntPredicate neg = x -> (x < 0);`.

Comment: "which is the case for all negative numbers"... except `Integer.MIN_VALUE` ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel your version doesn't look like ASCII art, its just readable.

Comment: @Gimby I like to check whether x is less than 3, because `x <3` expresses my love for x ;)

Comment: You can still use `x <- 0` if you like the “reverse lambda operator” so much…